# Number value as text

Tags: excel, excel-2008

I have a single cell with the value:

```
426,427,433,439,442
```

This isn't a number, rather a list of numbers. If I try to add another number to the list, for example, 679.  Excel changes the cell to read:

```
679,426,427,433,439,000
```

If I select the cell and format it as "text", it changes to:

```
 4.26427E+14
```

I've tried various cell formatting options, but I can't seem to get Excel to treat these numbers like text.

Comment: It's has to do with localization settings, but @Gary's student provided the best answer, I tested it myself

Comment: no, I copied the cells, changed formatting to text and then applied @Gary's student solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste the column into Notepad, format a new column in Excel as text. In Notepad select all, copy it back out from Notepad into the column in Excel that you formatted for text.

Comment: this will work best.  I've got a column with hundreds of these sets of numbers, some longer than others.  Do you know _why_ this solution works?

Comment: Only explanation I can give is because you are then going from and to places that have been told to be text. I know that's not a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

First place a single quote (*apostrophe*) in front of the set of numbers and add the latest value at the  <strike>end</strike>  appropriate position.

1. add (*apostrophe*) in front of numbers
2. add (*comma's*) between
3. add any number by adding a (*comma*)

Comment: While I upvoted this answer, please try to add the steps required to achieve this, as it wasn't straight forward for me even thought I got it to work.

Comment: then he should add it after the (apostrophe)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

```
=LEFT(A1,3)&","&MID(A1,4,3)&","&MID(A1,7,3)&","&MID(A1,10,3)&","&MID(A1,13,3)
```

It seems you have a number `426427433439442` with the commas purely a presentational aspect of the formatting. I take it you want the commas and the only way now may be to insert them.